# Photometry extinction correction magnitude

Tags: observational-astronomy, photometry

I am learning photometry and I am wondering is the uncorrected extinction instrumental magnitude always less than the corrected extinction instrumental magnitude when applying transformation coefficients?

For example suppose the uncorrected extinction instrumental magnitude is $m^A_V = 10.00,$ will the corrected extinction instrumental magnitude always be greater than $10$?

Comment: @KornpobBhirombhakdi Comments are not for answers.

Comment: I used to put short answer in 'answer' and that upset people because it was not long enough. I will leave a long version for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object has a measured brightness, then it's extinction-corrected brightness will always be higher. Hence the extinction-corrected magnitude will always be smaller than the uncorrected (observed) magnitude.